# Move Item path null

Tags: powershell, csv, file

I have to move files from a folder corresponding to a CSV column like that :

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1a | file1 |
| 2b | file2 |
| 3c | file3 |
| 4d | file4 |

So if in my folder I have a file named *file1* I need to create a folder named *1a* and put *file1* inside.

I have the following script

```
$CsvId = Import-Csv './test.csv'
$sourcePath= "C:\Users\olong\Desktop\object"
$dirPath = "C:\Users\olong\Desktop\dir"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath | ForEach-Object -Process {[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_)}
$pattern = '(?<=_).*(?=_)'  

ForEach ($item In $CsvId) {
   $objectID = $item.'id'
   $docID = $item.'name'  
   $location = $dirPath+ "\" + $objectID

  Foreach ($file in $files) {
       
    if($file -contains $docID) {
      if (-not (Test-Path -Path $location)) {
        mkdir -Path $location
    }

    Move-Item ($file.FullName) -Destination $location -Verbose -Force

}
}
}
```

But it gives me that error :

```
Move-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Users\olong\Desktop\scriptMove.ps1:19 char:15
+     Move-Item ($file.FullName) -Destination $location -Verbose -Force
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Move-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

With PowerShell's debugger $file is not null and with or without parenthesis on $file.FullName does nothing

Comment: `$files` contains path _strings_, therefore `$file` is also a path string, and a string has no `.FullName` property, so the property access attempts evaluates to `$null`.

Comment: Yes I saw that thank you, I tried to use the pattern regex to only use the filename(string) not the object itself, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what you want to do is to get the file(s) as mentioned in the csv under header 'name' having any extension into a subfolder as mentioned in field 'id' and create that subfolder first if it does not already exist.

If my assumtion is correct, you can try below:

```
$sourcePath      = "C:\Users\olong\Desktop\object"
$destinationPath = "C:\Users\olong\Desktop\dir"

Import-Csv -Path './test.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $targetDirectory = Join-Path -Path $destinationPath -ChildPath $_.id
    # create the output subfolder if it does not already exist
    $null = New-Item -Path $targetDirectory -ItemType Directory -Force
    # next use the file basename from the $_.name column as filter and move the file(s)
    Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Filter "$($_.name).*" -File | Move-Item -Destination $targetDirectory
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Theo you understood well what I have to do and your code is more readable and simplier than mine